# modifying spark GraphX pageRank to do random walk with restart

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pagerank, random-walk, spark-graphx

I am trying to implement random walk with restart by modifying the Spark GraphX implementation of PageRank algorithm.

```
  def randomWalkWithRestart(graph: Graph[VertexProperty, EdgeProperty], patientID: String , numIter: Int = 10, alpha: Double = 0.15, tol: Double = 0.01): Unit = {

var rankGraph: Graph[Double, Double] = graph
  // Associate the degree with each vertex
  .outerJoinVertices(graph.outDegrees) { (vid, vdata, deg) => deg.getOrElse(0) }
  // Set the weight on the edges based on the degree
  .mapTriplets( e => 1.0 / e.srcAttr, TripletFields.Src )
  // Set the vertex attributes to the initial pagerank values
  .mapVertices( (id, attr) => alpha )

var iteration = 0
var prevRankGraph: Graph[Double, Double] = null
while (iteration < numIter) {
  rankGraph.cache()

  // Compute the outgoing rank contributions of each vertex, perform local preaggregation, and
  // do the final aggregation at the receiving vertices. Requires a shuffle for aggregation.
  val rankUpdates = rankGraph.aggregateMessages[Double](
    ctx => ctx.sendToDst(ctx.srcAttr * ctx.attr), _ + _, TripletFields.Src)

  // Apply the final rank updates to get the new ranks, using join to preserve ranks of vertices
  // that didn't receive a message. Requires a shuffle for broadcasting updated ranks to the
  // edge partitions.
  prevRankGraph = rankGraph
  rankGraph = rankGraph.joinVertices(rankUpdates) {
    (id, oldRank, msgSum) => alpha + (1.0 - alpha) * msgSum
  }.cache()

  rankGraph.edges.foreachPartition(x => {}) // also materializes rankGraph.vertices
  //logInfo(s"PageRank finished iteration $iteration.")
  prevRankGraph.vertices.unpersist(false)
  prevRankGraph.edges.unpersist(false)

  iteration += 1

}
```

}

I believe the `(id, oldRank, msgSum) => alpha + (1.0 - alpha) * msgSum` part should be changed, but I am not sure how. I need to add the ready state probability to this line.

Furthermore, the ready state probability should be initialized somewhere before the `while` loop. And the ready state probability has to be uploaded inside the `while` loop.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do a personalized pagerank?

Comment: I am not sure modifying PageRank is the best implementation since it propagates out to every connected neighbor rather than 'walking' the graph.  You could do something like ConnectedComponents that propagates a label along path.  You would just need to have a vertex randomly pick one of its neighbors to send a positive value, while the other either do not get a message or are passed zero.

One of the issues with Spark is that it always operates across the whole graph, so doing a walk from one vertex becomes a challenge.